# Making ports visible to only certain domains

Tags: networking, domain

I have one server and multiple domains pointed at it. If I have a service on port 1234 on the server how can I make it so that service cannot be seen if checked from one domain but is visible from a second domain?

Comment: You need to configure virtual hosting on your web server.

Comment: Not web hosting

Comment: Then it's impossible. Once someone establishes a TCP connection or sends UDP packets on a port, there is no longer a concept of domains. It's just IP and ports from that point on, except at higher layers (such as web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Domains get resolved to IPs on most services. The only reason HTTP works in this way is because the protocol passes a "Host:" header. Nothing else does.

Comment: Thanks Nathan that's what i was thinking but just in case there was some work around I thought i would ask

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you could consider is to IPsec to require authentication from the web process associated with the specific web instance.